# Checking if a renderer is visible from a specific camera in Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, renderer

There used to be an ["isVisibleFrom"](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/IsVisibleFrom) method in Unity before, but now there isn't. Here is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class CheckPerspective : MonoBehaviour
{
    Renderer rend;

    void Start()
    {
        rend = GetComponent<Renderer>();
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (rend.isVisible)
        {
            print("hi");
        }
    }
}
```

This code prints "hi" when I'm looking at the object, but this happens even if I'm looking at it from the editor camera.

I want to use something like "isVisibleFrom" to not let this happen.
 Is there anything else I can use or do?

Comment: You can use this extension [isVisibleFrom](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/IsVisibleFrom) method.

Comment: @AliKanat I did try. It says " 'Renderer' does not contain a definition for 'isVisibleFrom'... "

Comment: I use it all the time. I don't see why it would not work for you. Did name name the script correctly?

Comment: That's intersting. Maybe we are using different versions of unity.

Comment: @Qedized you need to make a script in your project with the code on that page for the extension

Comment: Well, I'm not so sure how to do that... Do you have the code?

Comment: @Qedized so copy the code from `C# - RendererExtensions.cs` into a script in your project named `RendererExtensions.cs` and then that function will be available to you.  All the code you need is on that page.

Comment: OH, I'm so sorry. Noob question. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @Qedized no problem, I would recommend looking up extension methods in unity, they are incredibly helpful!  And can make your life 100x easier then have to redo the same stuff over and over again!

Comment: I will definitely check it out. Thanks again!